# Python inherit from tk.Frame with internal Layout and Scrollbars

Tags: python, oop, tkinter, scrollbar, frame

I have  worked with the AutoScrollbar (http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-autoscrollbar.htm), and added a horizontal one too.

```
from Tkconstants import VERTICAL, N, S, HORIZONTAL, W, E, END
import Tkinter as Tk
class AutoScrollbar(Tk.Scrollbar):
    """ a scrollbar that hides itself if it's not needed.  only
    works if you use the grid geometry manager."""
    def set(self, lo, hi):
        if float(lo) <= 0.0 and float(hi) >= 1.0:
            # grid_remove is currently missing from Tkinter!
            self.tk.call("grid", "remove", self)
        else:
            self.grid()
        Tk.Scrollbar.set(self, lo, hi)
    def pack(self, **kw):
        raise Tk.TclError, "cannot use pack with this widget"
    def place(self, **kw):
        raise Tk.TclError, "cannot use place with this widget"


if __name__ == '__main__':  
    root = Tk.Tk()
    scrollbarY = AutoScrollbar(root,orient=VERTICAL)
    scrollbarY.grid(column=1, row=0,sticky=N+S)
    scrollbarX = AutoScrollbar(root,orient=HORIZONTAL)
    scrollbarX.grid(column=0, row=1,sticky=W+E)

    mylist = Tk.Listbox(root, xscrollcommand = scrollbarX.set, yscrollcommand = scrollbarY.set )
    for line in range(50):
        mylist.insert(END, "This is line number " + str(line) + ", and then just for whatever reason this text goes on and on")

    mylist.grid(column=0, row=0,sticky=N+S+E+W)
    scrollbarX.config( command = mylist.xview )
    scrollbarY.config( command = mylist.yview )


    root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    Tk.mainloop()
```

Now I thought: wouldn't it be rad to have this functionality without all the clutter?
So I set out to code a tk.Frame with autohiding scrollbars.
The Idea is: you add a Widget to the AutoscrollFrame, the Atuoscrollframe internally puts that widget at (0,0) on a 2x2 grid, with (0,1) and (1,0) being x- and y- autohiding scrollbars and (1,1) being left blank.
The scrollbars would of course only be visible if they are needed.

Now this idea seemed pretty easy to implement in my head. Sadly I soon saw that it wasn't.
What method do I have to override to implement the 'add child widget to frame' functionality (that adds the widget not to the frame in general but to the (0,0) grid position and also registers the scrollbars with the widget)?

My code so far looks like this:

```
import Tkinter as tk
from Tkconstants import VERTICAL, N, S, HORIZONTAL, W, E, END


class AutoscrollFrame(tk.Frame):
    """A Frame extension that automatically adds scrollbars
    if the content of the frame exceeds it's dimensions.
    """


    def __init__(self,master,*args,**kwargs):
        self.master = master
        super(AutoscrollFrame,self).__init__(master=master,*args,**kwargs)
        self.scrollbarY = _AutoScrollbar(self,orient=VERTICAL)
        self.scrollbarY.grid(column=1, row=0,sticky=N+S)
        self.scrollbarX = _AutoScrollbar(self,orient=HORIZONTAL)
        self.scrollbarX.grid(column=0, row=1,sticky=W+E)

        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)


    def add_child_placeholder(self,child):
        self.child = child
        self.child.config(xscrollcommand=scrollbarX.set, yscrollcommand=scrollbarY.set )
        self.child.grid(column=0, row=0,sticky=N+S+E+W)
        self.scrollbarX.config( command = self.child.xview )
        self.scrollbarY.config( command = self.child.yview )
```

the `add_child_placeholder` is a prototype for the method I'd like to call when something like this happens:

```
frame = AutoscrollFrame(root)
myList = tk.Listbox(frame)
```

meaning if I set the frame as master to another Widget, I want to call the frames `add_child_placeholder` method.
Is this a sensible way to do it? I'm not totally sure this isn't a brainfart, so a little help would be greatly appreciated.

PS: I wanted to add this functionality to tk.Frame (as opposed to tk.ListBox) since I'm not yet sure if Listbox is what I will end up using.

Comment: `self.child.config('xscrollcommand'=scrollbarX.set,...` should be `self.child.config(xscrollcommand=scrollbarX.set, ...`

Comment: Sure enough. Corrected it.

Comment: @DaniGehtdichnixan honestly, use some Tk extension for that (like Tix or Bwidget which have this functionality). A frame isn't scrollable, so you will have to fake it by placing it in another widget (like Text or Canvas).